# Wrapper causes change in the funcName attribute in custom python logger

Tags: python, logging, wrapper

I have created a wrapper in custom python logger to add additional attributes in the log formatter.

```
logFormat = logging.Formatter('[%(levelname)s],[%(asctime)-15s], %(API_SERVER)s, %(funcName)s,%(lineno)d, %(message)s')
```

Additional Attribute -> API_SERVER

The log shows the wrapper method as the funcName instead of actual funcName.

```
[DEBUG],[2017-05-23 17:52:13,865], jupiter-api-server, loggingMethodsWrapper,91, Response returned from DolphinD is 200, returning status success, to caller.
```

Wrapper Code -->

```
def loggingMethodsWrapper(self, logLevelMethod, *kargs):
    # Calling method logging methods dynamcially
    # Add the parameters in the extra if you want to add
    # more columns in logging format
    getattr(self.log, logLevelMethod)(
          *kargs, extra={'API_SERVER': self.API_SERVER})
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find it in off documentation, but if we check the source code for methods debug/info/error/etc..., we can simply change 'stacklevel' to change the caller name

In your wrapper, you probably want to add smth like that:

```
loggerWrapper.debug("log text", *args, stacklevel=<N>)
```

where is N - is the number of levels to look up to find a correct caller.

from logger sources:

```
 def _log(self, level, msg, args, exc_info=None, extra=None, stack_info=False,
             stacklevel=1):
```

Comment: Actually documentation states that default value of stacklevel is 1. In my case, it worked when stting the stacklevel to 2. I then got the function name from the caller. Imho, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The wrong function name is happening because `loggingMethodsWrapper` is the one actually doing the call to log.

What you want seems to be function that calls loggingMethodsWrapper. The fix is to change your formatter so that it doesn't include `%(funcName)s` and move that to be part of the arguments passed to `%(message)s` or as an extra parameter.

### Opt 1:

Doing this, a dirty fix would be to have your wrapper walk up the stack and grab the next function up.

In python2 this would like:

```
caller = inspect.stack()[1][3]
```

On python3 this would be:

```
caller = inspect.stack()[1].filename
```

So:

```
logFormat = logging.Formatter('[%(levelname)s],[%(asctime)-15s], %(API_SERVER)s, %(CALLER)s,%(lineno)d, %(message)s')

...

def loggingMethodsWrapper(self, logLevelMethod, *kargs):
    caller = # python-specific method of getting caller
    getattr(self.log, logLevelMethod)(
          *kargs, extra={'CALLER' : caller, 'API_SERVER': self.API_SERVER})
```

### Opt 2:

Simple fix if you can change caller -- passing the function name to your logger wrapper

```
loggingMethodsWrapper(self, func_name, logLevelMethod, *kargs):
    ....
```

and then when you call it

```
def foo():
    loggingMethodsWrapper(foo.__name__, log_level, ...)
```

Comment: loggingMethodWrapper() is a part of my custom log.py file. I have 100s of API files that call Log() and I can't call foo() in all the files. Could you please suggest an alternative that doesn't require making changes in all the files? @xgord

Comment: When I call an API (say Accounts), the log() gets called. The expected funcName in the log file should be get_accounts but it shows loggingMethodsWrapper.

Comment: @TanuSachdeva I updated it with an alternate way. It could be helpful though if you update your question with one example of how `log` is being called and how the `log` is set

Comment: also just to clarify the first comment. I'm not saying add a function `foo` to your library. It's just an example of a function calling your log wrapper and how the call would have to change.

Comment: I have already tried option 1, inspect.stack[1][3] returns "None".

Comment: @TanuSachdeva please update/edit your question with that code. it's impossible to read in the comments

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience. I have added the codes for Log and the API. @xgord

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I had number of different functions, wrote nice and clean wrapper with logging. In that situation of course I need to have feedback, what function it is. I copied [source from github](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c66fc0fb53b5316dc325fde3bc738890515d38a4/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1589), that is responsible for that pain, and deleted just few lines

```
# enable overwritting log record attributes
# I know, dirty cheating



def makeRecord(self, name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info,
               func=None, extra=None, sinfo=None):
"""
A factory method which can be overridden in subclasses to create
specialized LogRecords.
"""
rv = logging._logRecordFactory(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func,
                               sinfo)
if extra is not None:
    for key in extra:
        rv.__dict__[key] = extra[key]
return rv


logging.Logger.makeRecord = makeRecord
```

than changed reference for that method in Logger class
so now I can set attributes of LogRecord, even if they are already used, like funcName

so wrapper looks like this

```
def log_string_convertors(convertor: callable):
    @wraps(convertor)
    def wrapper(string: str):
        result: str = convertor(string)
        logger.debug("%s->%s", string, result,
                 extra={"input": string, "output": result, "funcName": convertor.__name__})
    return result

return wrapper
```

I am saving LogRecords to json to be able to analyze them with program later, so I am adding some additional attributes like input and output

Answer (score 0):

Log.py

```
class Log(Singleton):
log = None
caller = None
def __init__(self):
    ### Configure log
    # TODO: The config has to come from Dictconfig YAML file
    logFolder = CONSTANTS['LOG']['DIR']
    self.API_SERVER = API_SERVER
    caller = inspect.stack()[1][3]
    print caller
    self.log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    # If handlers are already set donot do it again
    if not len(self.log.handlers):
        logFormat = logging.Formatter('[%(levelname)s],[%(asctime)-15s], %(API_SERVER)s, %(caller)s,%(lineno)d, %(message)s')
```

---

```
def loggingMethodsWrapper(self, logLevelMethod, *kargs):
    # Calling method logging methods dynamically
    # Add the parameters in the extra if you want to add
    # more columns in logging format

    getattr(self.log, logLevelMethod)(
          *kargs, extra={'API_SERVER': self.API_SERVER, 'caller': self.caller})
```

Example API File -->

```
from flask import Flask, Response, request
from base import base
from jupiter_api.lib.jupFlaskClassy import *

from jupiter_api.business.accounts import accounts as bzAccounts
from jupiter_api.business.role_decorators import permGate, login_required
from flask.ext.cors import CORS
from jupiter_api.utils.log import Log
Log = Log()

class accounts(base):

    supported_methods = "OPTIONS, GET, POST, DELETE"
    ##  GET request to pull all user accounts
    @route('/<userId>/<companyId>/accounts/<accountId>', methods=['GET'])
    @permGate('list_accounts')
    @login_required
    def get_details(self, userId, companyId, accountId):
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        Log.debug("In get accounts for user")

        # Validate arguments
        if not userId or not companyId:
            return self.invalidData()

        # Print arguments
        Log.debug("Getting account details for user %s ", userId)
```

Note - I have 100s of APIs similar to the Accounts API that are calling Log().

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inspect` package to get previous function's name. Here's an example of singleton wrapper of logging functionality that shows 'true' caller:

```
import logging
import inspect

class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class MyLogger(metaclass=Singleton):
    logger = None

    def __init__(self):
        logging.basicConfig(
            level=logging.INFO,
            format="%(asctime)s - %(threadName)s - %(message)s",
            handlers=[
                logging.StreamHandler()
            ])

        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__ + '.logger')

    @staticmethod
    def __get_call_info():
        stack = inspect.stack()

        # stack[1] gives previous function (info in our case)
        # stack[2] gives before previous function and so on

        fn = stack[2][1]
        ln = stack[2][2]
        func = stack[2][3]

        return fn, func, ln

    def info(self, message, *args):
        message = "{} - {} at line {}: {}".format(*self.__get_call_info(), message)
        self.logger.info(message, *args)
```